# Subdomain For Online Multivendor Shopping Store

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I develop multi-vendor online store and i want when vendor register and enter shop name than auto shopname make a sub-domain and vendor products show thier sub-domain 
   like shopping.local 
and when vendor register his shop name make 
like shopname.shopping.local